# 400 Bad Request with Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, ajax, adsense

I am running a website that uses AJAX requests and history.pushState for navigation.

The requested content code contains Google's asynchronus AdSense code:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

The head tag contains the adsbygoogle.js:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

This setup is working for one dynamically loaded pageview. After that, ads don't show up anymore. The error console shows:

```
400 (Bad Request) in expansion_embed.js:188
```

The expansion_embed.js requests the ad from http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads. The requestet url contains lots of parameters.

Now, every time the ad **does** show up, the `prev_fmts` parameter has a value of `468x60`. If the ad fails to load, this parameter's value is `486x60%2C468x60`.

What is causing this parameter to change? Is it possible that this change is causing the 400 Bad Request errors?

Comment: post the relevant code from empansion_embed

Comment: expansion_embed.js is a minified script that is hosted by google. It's a bit tricky to find the relevant code.

Comment: is it possible that your selector `adsbygoogle` is selecting more than 1 element?

Comment: same problem here, all ads loading but one, i have no clue why 

btw same adv size

Comment: I had a ton of these errors from Google AdSense after making lots of changes to my site. I cleared my cache in Chrome and all went away.

Comment: data-ad-format="fluid" attribute solved for me

Answer (score 63):

You just need to wait, when you first implement Adsense it will give this error. It took until next morning for Adsense to start displaying ads. I implemented their Responsive ad type.

Comment: Took about an hour for me. Weird that there's a delay!

Comment: what's weird is 400 instead of anything else and no warning in the AdSense dashboard.

Comment: @AndreiMotinga yep, that's how they roll

Comment: yeah it tooks 1 hour

Comment: Now it took me about only 15 minutes which is far better than an hour or more, but still so lame...

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this issue? I am running angular 7 SSR with ng2-AdSense. Been getting 400 errors for about a week now. Did anyone install with angular SSR?

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting same error when I added adsense code first time in my website. In my case, it started working simply after reloading page.

Comment: In my case, it started working after reloading around 5 times

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and after some research, I've seen it's a problem of incompatibility between Google Adsens and AJAX sites.

See [Google's announcement](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/) and these [two](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/YEl7M9BqC-4) [threads](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/GUfOVxtOl3c) in Google's forums.

I've tried to artifically mangle the `prev_fmts` parameter, but I couldn't find my way through the obfuscated JS. Anyway, I guess that doing this would go against Google Adsense TOS.

Answer (score -1):

Adblock was blocking the ads. I Enabled the site to solved it.

Comment: AdBlock really block the ads but with different error code. The error 400 is different and still occurs with disabled AdBlock. I had to wait ~15 minutes, and the problem was gone.

Comment: This fix my problem. Thanks

Comment: Nope. Adblock blocks using net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, or anything else, but it cannot use 400.